# How to only paste to clipboard if it's not already there

Tags: java, android, clipboard, clipboardmanager

I'm letting the user long click on a `TextView` and that will copy the text of the `TextView` to their `Clipboard`.

I want it so that before it will actually copy the text of the `TextView` to their `Clipboard`, it will check if the last `Clip` on their `Clipboard` is the different than the text.

Here is the code:

```
ClipboardManager clipboard =(ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
String text = textView.getText().toString();

   if ( !(clipboard.getPrimaryClip().toString().equals(text)) )
// if ( !(clipboard.getPrimaryClip().equals(text)) )
   {
       clipboard.setPrimaryClip(ClipData.newPlainText("newClipName", text));
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Copied to clipboard.", 0).show(); 
   }
```

I can only imagine that the method `getPrimaryClip()` is not returning a `String` and `toString()` also doesn't work. How can I get the most recent `Clip` as a `String`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClipboardManager clipboard=(ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
String text = textView.getText().toString();

// item is the most recent Clip from the Clipboard
ClipData.Item item = clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0);

// Gets the clipboard as text.
String clipText = item.getText().toString(); // getText() returns CharSequence

if ( !(clipText.equals(text)) )
{
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(ClipData.newPlainText("newClipName", text));
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Copied to clipboard.", 0).show(); 
}
```